# Help with probability mass function, specifically understanding sample mean

Tags: probability, statistics

The question is

Let $X$ be a discrete random variable with probability mass function

[image]

(a) Find $E(X)$ 
I did $E(X) = -2*.3+ -1*6 + 12*.1 = -5.4$
(b) Find $Var(X)$ 
 I did $E(x^{2})-(E(x))^{2}= (-2^{2} * .3 + -1*.6 + 12*.1) - (-5.4)^{2} = -29.76$ 
(c) Find expected value of X(bar) (the sample mean) 
 Would this just be the same thing as $E(X)$?
(d) if n = 100, what is the variance of X(bar)? 
 would I just multiply the variance by 100?

Last question is if I wanted to put this all in R, how would I input my CDF into R and find the expected value and variance, etc. I understand it on paper (most of the time) but I am unsure how I would put it in R, any help is appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

(a) Your calculation was off.  It seems that you dropped the decimal.$$\mathsf E(X)=−2\cdot 0.3+−1\cdot \underbrace{0.6}+12\cdot0.1=0.0$$

(b) A negative variance is an error warning.   You need to square *each* supported value when you multiply by the probability mass.$$\mathsf{Var}(X)=((−2)^2\cdot 0.3+(−1)^2\cdot 0.6+(12)^2\cdot0.1) -(0.0)^2= 16.2$$

(c) The *expected sample mean* is indeed the expected value of the distribution.   We just apply the Linearity of expectation, and *identical distribution* of the samples: $$\begin{align}\mathsf E(\bar X)&=\mathsf E\left(\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^nX_i}{n}\right)\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n\mathsf E(X_i)}{n}\\[1ex]&=\mathsf E(X_1)\\[1ex]&=\mathsf E(X)\end{align}$$

(d) For the variance of the sample mean, you must apply the Bilinearity of Covariance, and the *independence* and identical distribution of the samples.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf {Var}(\overline X)&=\mathsf{Var}\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nX_i}{n}\right)\\[1ex]&=\frac 1{n^2}\mathsf {Cov}(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i,\sum_{j=1}^n X_j)\\[1ex]&~~\vdots\end{align}$$

Comment: So would c) essentially be 0 and d) would be 16.2/n which would be .162?

Comment: @overlord12  That is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to square the x's before multiplying and then adding.
$$E[X^2] = (-2)^2\cdot 0.3 + (-1)^2 \cdot 0.6 + (12)^2\cdot 0.1 = 1.2 + 0.6 + 14.4 = 16.2$$
When you multiply a variable by $c$, you multiply the mean of it by $c$ and the standard deviation by $c$, which means the variance is multiplied by $c^2$.  The expected value of a sum is the sum of the expected values.

In R, you could construct a vector of $X$ values and a vector of $p$ values

$x \leftarrow c(-2,-1,12)$

$p \leftarrow c(0.3, 0.6, 0.1)$

I'm afraid I don't know the sampling functions in R very well yet. I have used the ones in the rethinking module.

Comment: So would c) essentially be 0 and d) would be 16.2/n which would be .162?

Comment: For the expected value of the mean, use linearity of expectation: $E(aX+b) = aE(X) + b.$  Since a sample is automatically independent random variables, you can also do $E(X_1 + X_2) = E(X_1) + E(X_2)$ and so forth.